# Сползает текст после изменения размера Layout

Tags: android, android-layout

У меня есть LinearLayout -> TableLayout -> TableRow -> TextView. Когда я изменяю размер LinearLayout у меня сползает текст в TextView. Как это исправить? В чем проблема?

Вот так меняю размер:

```
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams lp = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
        lp.setMargins(0, 400, 120, 0);

linearLayout.setLayoutParams(lp);
```

А вот скрин сползания:

[image]

Comment: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams.html#setMargins(int, int, int, int)

Comment: у вас после изменения размеров родителя, дочерние элементы не меняют размеры и отступы которые заданы конкретным значением

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Этим кодом вы меняете положение формы, но если вам нужно саму форму уменьшить 
попробуйте

`layout.setScaleX(scaleX);
layout.setScaleY(scaleY);`

где scaleX и scaleY дробные значеня меньше 1. Например 0.5f уменьшит в 2 раза